# Spring boot app showing 404 for index.html

Tags: spring-boot

I have a Spring boot application and a static index.html file located in src/main/resources/static

my controller is straight forward and looks like this

```
@Controller
@Log4j
public class StartController {

    @Autowired
    OwnerRepository ownerRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";


    }

}
```

my only configuration is the main one and it only has the @SpringBootApplication
Im getting 404 when I hit the URL, as per my understanding no further configuration is needed
by the way in the logs on the startup im seeing the following

> URI Template variables for request [/index] are {}

here is my POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.datasol</groupId>
    <artifactId>alquifacil</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>AlquiFacil</name>
    <description>spring boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

html is a static resource
so you can access by "localhost:8080/index.html"
or
use "forward" keyword

```java
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
   //has to be without blank spaces
   return "forward:index.html";
}
```

Comment: Its still giving me 404 i placed the index.html in the static folder

Comment: i edited your answer and removed the blanck space in the return , its now working without any additional configuration (spring boot)

Answer (score 8):

On your pom.xml i didn't see any template engine like Thymeleaf, Velocity ecc but you have **spring-boot-starter-web**, so basically  you **resource folder its configurated,** but you should put your file index.html on **templates folder.** Static folder serve to contain your asset files.

If you are working local, try: 
[**localhost:8080/**](http://localhost:8080/) or [**localhost:8080/alquifacil/**](http://localhost:8080/alquifacil/) assuming you are using port 8080 or add a template engine dependency in pom.xml like Thymeleaf

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: While this will work, i really dont want to use thymeleaf, just normla HTML

Answer (score 1):

please delete the target file and run again. it can be a cashing problem.